# Why is my TI-BASIC program displaying the wrong outputs in a guessing game?

Tags: ti-basic

I am very new to TI-BASIC, and I've been trying to make a guessing game. The code outputs no errors, but displays the wrong version of "higher" or "lower" when you put in a number

Here is the code:

```
ClrHome
randInt(1,100)→N
For(B,1,10)
Input "Guess a number: ",A
If A=N:Then
Disp "You did it"
Stop
Else
If A>N:Then
Disp "You are higher"
Else
Disp "You are lower"
End
End
End
Disp "You lose"
Disp "The number was",N
Stop
```

Comment: please show the "wrong output" and what output you expected.

Comment: This code seems like it should work, and I've been able to successfully run it..Are you sure that this is the code as you typed it? Can you be more specific about what wrong output you've been getting?